# Is it bad practice to use :root with asterisk (CSS universal selector) to override Bootstrap variables?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to theme my site, which uses Bootstrap, by modifying the Bootstrap variables.  Bootstrap defines some variables against the `:root` element, allowing me to override them in a straightforward way:

```
:root {
    --bs-body-color: red;
}
```

However others are defined against selectors, such as `--bs-navbar-color`.  In order to override this (and not worry about the specific selectors I need to specify), I need to apply the style universally:

```
:root * {
    --bs-navbar-color: blue !important;
}
```

Is this considered bad practice?  It seems to work, and although it might be considered a bad idea for regular styles, it seems to me that it's not too much of a problem when just dealing with CSS variables.

Comment: i'd keep the specificity as low as possibile, so instead of setting that color to every element I'd just override it with `html:root` (which is more specific than `:root`) and no `!important` at all.

Comment: *Is this considered bad practice?* Yeah. You should use the specific selectors.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan That wouldn't override the variables like `--bs-navbar-color` though, which are set specifially on classes like `navbar`.  They need to have the variable applied directly to the element to override them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/css-variables/). When you want to override any variable you can  declare them in `:root` without *all* selector and without *important*. It is important to import/use your override CSS **after** you include Bootstrap - not before.

Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
:root {
   --bs-danger-rgb: 0,0,250;
}
</style>
<div class="bg-danger">It's blue</div>
```

---

### Component variables

If you want to change a variable of a specific component, then selecting everything `*` is unnecessary - the variable is only in that component anyway. Whilst the `*` method will work, it's probably better practice to override the variable using the correct selector against which the variable is defined, such as `.navbar` for `--bs-navbar-color`, which will avoid the need to use `!important`. The selector you need to use for the variable is well-defined in the Bootstrap documentation. See quotes from the documentation:

> Whenever possible, we’ll assign CSS variables at the base component level (e.g., **.navbar for navbar** and its sub-components). This reduces guessing on where and how to customize, and allows for easy modifications by our team in future updates.
>
> Source: [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/css-variables/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.navbar {
   --bs-navbar-color: blue;
}
</style>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-text">
    It's blue
  </div>
</div>
```

However I find [using the SASS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/) as the correct solution to theming Bootstrap.

Comment: I specifically addressed that.  Some variables are defined at `:root` level, but others like `--bs-navbar-color` are not and require the `*` selector to override.

Comment: @Jez I edited the answer about the component variable from the documentation.

Comment: This answer is better than the official documentation itself.